# Splitting a string into n-length chunks in Java

Tags: java, string, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split string to equal length substrings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760152/split-string-to-equal-length-substrings-in-java)

Given the following utility method I have:

```
/**
 * Splits string <tt>s</tt> into chunks of size <tt>chunkSize</tt>
 *
 * @param s the string to split; must not be null
 * @param chunkSize number of chars in each chuck; must be greater than 0
 * @return The original string in chunks
 */
public static List<String> splitInChunks(String s, int chunkSize) {
    Preconditions.checkArgument(chunkSize > 0);
    List<String> result = Lists.newArrayList();
    int length = s.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i += chunkSize) {
        result.add(s.substring(i, Math.min(length, i + chunkSize)));
    }
    return result;
}
```

1) **Is there an equivalent method in any common Java library** (such as Apache Commons, Google Guava) so  I could throw it away from my codebase? Couldn't find with a quick look. Whether it returns an array or a List of Strings doesn't really matter.

(Obviously I wouldn't add dependency to some huge framework just for this, but feel free to mention any common lib; maybe I use it already.)

2) **If not, is there some simpler and cleaner way to do this in Java?** Or a way that is strikingly more performant? (If you suggest a regex-based solution, please also consider cleanness in the sense of readability for non regex experts... :-)

**Edit**: this qualifies as a duplicate of the question "[Split string to equal length substrings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760152/split-string-of-equal-lengths-in-java)"  because of **[this Guava solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760152/split-string-to-equal-length-substrings-in-java/3760862#3760862)** which perfectly answers my question!

Comment: I agree it's a duplicate. Or, rather, the question isn't an exact dupe, but the answers contain your [beautiful Guava solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760152/split-string-of-equal-lengths-in-java/3760862#3760862) which is exactly what I want!

Comment: @seanizer: I did look at Guava's `Strings` class, but I had completely missed the existence of `Splitter`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do this with Guava's [Splitter](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html):

```
 Splitter.fixedLength(chunkSize).split(s)
```

...which returns an `Iterable<String>`.

Some more examples in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760152/split-string-to-equal-length-substrings-in-java/3760862#3760862).

Comment: I don't deserve the credit.  I ripped that right out of the OP's code.

Comment: Of course, I'd dump my own utility method and just use Splitter directly now that I'm aware of it, but thanks for pointing out Guava can do this!

Comment: Heh, this is going to be closed, and the answer I'd like to accept is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760152/split-string-to-equal-length-substrings-in-java/3760862#3760862)... Hmm, but wait, let me edit this answer to my liking first, and the I'll give you the extra points. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Mostly a duplicate of [Split Java String in chunks of 1024 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520907/split-java-string-in-chunks-of-1024-bytes) where the idea of turning it into a stream and reading N bytes at a time would seem to meet your need?

[Here is a way of doing it with regex](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5282416&start=15) (which seems a bit of a sledgehammer for this particular nut)